# How to Access AWS S3 Bucket in Python using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sh, boto3, aws-cli

I'm a data engineering student who is just getting started. Below is the link to a public S3 dataset that holds both archived and real-time weather radar reports.

https://registry.opendata.aws/noaa-nexrad/

I was able to easily access the archived data using the nexradaws module in Python. However, I am having trouble accessing the real-time dataset in Python, as it is not offered within the nexradaws module.

I read some stackoverflow posts that somewhat pertain to this and found a few different approaches:

1. Use boto3 package - I tried this but boto3 documentation seems to focus on creating buckets within Python. Then, accessing those buckets using an access key and secret key. However, this bucket does not required credentials to access. Not sure what is the proper way to implement boto3 in my case. Additionally, I've gone through the official boto3 documentation and was not able to find information on how to access public buckets that do not requires access keys. But, just in case, I did setup an AWS account and tried using the ARN when creating a bucket, however, the created bucket is still empty.
2. Use subprocess module within Python and run AWS CLI - I'm also trying this but having trouble finding the correct way to implement AWS CLI within the subprocess module.
3. Use brilliant sh Python package - Trying this, I am having the same issue as above.

My questions are, how can I access the real-time data using boto3? and how can I download the data? Where are some good resources for boto3?

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not an opinion-based forum. I recommend checking out [SoftwareRecs Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and/or [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Voting to close.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my question. It is no long opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `boto3`:

```py
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.resource("s3", config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
bucket = s3.Bucket("noaa-nexrad-level2")

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="2021/01/01"):
    print(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks. But where would the link to the actual bucket go?

Comment: It's already there, under `s3.Bucket("noaa-nexrad-level2")`. This is specifically the NEXRAD Level II archive data.

Comment: I see. That is actually the archived data, which I already accessed using nexradaws module. I changed it to "unidata-nexrad-level2-chunks ", but now I'm unsure how to filter it, as the objects.filter() does not return anything with this bucket.

Comment: Just tried with `unidata-nexrad-level2-chunks`, and I personally see results. Make sure to remove `Prefix="..."`, as that is your filtering parameter.