# How do I access S3 using Boto3 in a Flask application when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this Python Flask API that uses BOTO3 to access S3:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError, ClientError

application = app = Flask(__name__)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

@app.route('/list-buckets', methods=['GET'])
def list_buckets():
    try:
        response = s3.list_buckets()
        buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in response.get('Buckets', [])]
        return jsonify(buckets)
    except NoCredentialsError:
        return jsonify(error="no credentials"), 401
    except ClientError as e:
        return jsonify(error=str(e)), 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here are the steps I took in console to configure the AWS CLI. These were ONLY done on my local environment.

- Install AWS CLI
- Run aws configure

  - Access key: [placeholder]
  - Access secret: [placeholder]
    When I run this API LOCALLY and access the list-buckets endpoint, I get the expected response which is the S3 buckets on the account.
    However, when I deploy and run this API and access the list-buckets endpoint, I get this error:

    - `"error": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied"`

I have tried adding the S3 Full access role to everything associated with this however I still get this same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Access AWS S3 Bucket in Python using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039443/how-to-access-aws-s3-bucket-in-python-using-boto3)